# Displaying last modified date in PHP

Tags: php

I have a question regarding a piece of PHP code.

I use this code to print the content of the "upload" folder. Each file has it's own `<div>` and the printed text is kinda like this: file name + extension.

```
    <?php
$dir   = "upload/"; // the directory that is being checked
$exclude = array(".", "..");
$files = scandir($dir);
$files = array_diff($files, $exclude);
if(!empty($files)) // check if the files array is not empty
{
    foreach ($files as $file) // print every file in the files array
        print "
<div class='fileicon'>
<div id='hint'>
<a href='upload/$file' style='text-decoration: none;' download>
<p class='filetext'>$file</p>
</a>
</div>
</div>";
}
else 
{
    echo "There are no files in directory"; // print error message if there are no files
}
?>
```

My question is... Is there any possible way through which I could display the date when the printed files were last modified?

I thought about using `filemtime` but I have no idea how to use it in the current context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($files as $file){
  echo date ("F d Y H:i:s", filemtime($file));
}
```

It helps to read the manual, especially the examples. What did you try so far? The above should work fine.

Comment: I tried something similar, but my code didn't return anything. Your example returned: "Warning: filemtime() failed to stat for.." Could it be  because of the server? I remember reading something on a blog about how filemtime might not work on all servers

Comment: I got it! I kept getting that error because `filemtime($file)` reffers to the current folder. I simply had to write `filemtime("upload/$file")`. Not sure if the quotes were requiered, but it's working! Thank you very much :)